# setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have component as below:

```
const VIEW_PROFILE = 'profile'
const VIEW_SAA = 'saa'
const VIEW_DOCUMENTS = 'documents'
const VIEW_FINANCIERS = 'viewFinancierInfo'

class ViewFinancier extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      selectedNavigation: VIEW_PROFILE,
      financierId: this.props.location.state.financierDetails.financierId,
      defaultLoading: false
    }

    this.handleChangeNav = this.handleChangeNav.bind(this)
    this.handleCancelButton = this.handleCancelButton.bind(this)
  }

  componentWillMount(props) {
    this.props.loadFinancierProfile(this.props.location.state.financierDetails.financierId)
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    this.setState({
      defaultLoading: true,
      viewfinancierprofiledata: newProps.viewfinancierprofiledata
    })
  }

  handleChangeNav(e) {
    var selectedNavigation = e.target.attributes.getNamedItem('value').value
    this.setState({
      selectedNavigation: selectedNavigation
    })
  }

  handleCancelButton(changingState) {
    this.setState({
      selectedNavigation: changingState
    })
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.defaultLoading === false) {
      return (
        <div className="tabledataloading tabletext">
          Please wait while the data is loading <img alt="Loading..." src={loadingimg} />
        </div>
      )
    } else if (this.state.selectedNavigation === VIEW_FINANCIERS) {
      this.props.history.push('/financier/')
      return null
    } else {
      return (
        <div id="lesse-info-component-wrapper" className="melody-common-container">
          <div id="header-wrapper">
            <h1 className="melody-common-module-title">VIEW FINANCIER INFO</h1>
          </div>
          <div id="navigation-wrapper">
            <ul id="add-financier-info-nav" className="topnavpad">
              <li
                value={VIEW_PROFILE}
                onClick={this.handleChangeNav}
                className={'add-financier-info-nav-item ' + (this.state.selectedNavigation === VIEW_PROFILE ? 'active' : '')}>
                PROFILE
              </li>
              <li
                value={VIEW_SAA}
                onClick={this.handleChangeNav}
                className={'add-financier-info-nav-item ' + (this.state.selectedNavigation === VIEW_SAA ? 'active' : '')}>
                SAA
              </li>
              <li
                value={VIEW_DOCUMENTS}
                onClick={this.handleChangeNav}
                className={'add-financier-info-nav-item ' + (this.state.selectedNavigation === VIEW_DOCUMENTS ? 'active' : '')}>
                DOCUMENTS
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          {this.state.selectedNavigation === VIEW_PROFILE
            ? <ViewFinancierProfile financierId={this.props.financierId} onCancelHandler={this.handleCancelButton} />
            : null}
          {this.state.selectedNavigation === VIEW_SAA
            ? <ViewFinancierSAA financierId={this.props.financierId} onCancelHandler={this.handleCancelButton} />
            : null}
          {this.state.selectedNavigation === VIEW_DOCUMENTS
            ? <ViewFinancierDocument financierId={this.props.financierId} onCancelHandler={this.handleCancelButton} />
            : null}
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    viewfinancierprofiledata: state.viewfinancierprofiledata
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    loadFinancierProfile: financierId => dispatch(viewFinancierProfileAction.loadFinancierProfile(financierId))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ViewFinancier)
```

And on execution I am getting the warning:`Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within`render`or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to`componentWillMount`

On looking into the console I found that the snippet `this.props.history.push('/financier/')` is throwing the error.

On further research in other similar questions in Stack Overflow, I also found that this actually setting the parents state under render method, which is not allowed.

But now I cannot figure out how I can achieve the condition I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component `props` should not be mutated by itself. I think there are 2 solutions for you in this situation.

1. Copy `this.props.history` to `state`, and mutate `history` by calling `setState`. Put the checking of `selectedNavigation` outside of `render`. For example (just my idea, please modify it base on your application logical):

```html
class ViewFinancier extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      ...
      history = props.history,
      ...
    }
    ...
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    this.setState({
      history: newProps.history,
      ...
    })
  }
  
  handleChangeNav(e) {
    var selectedNavigation = e.target.attributes.getNamedItem('value').value;
    
    this.setState({
      selectedNavigation: selectedNavigation      
    })
    
    this.historyCheck(selectedNavigation);
  }

  handleCancelButton(changingState) {
    this.setState({
      selectedNavigation: changingState
    });
    
    this.historyCheck(changingState);
  }
  
  historyCheck(nav) {
    if (nav === VIEW_FINANCIERS) {
      history.push('/financier/');
    };
    
    this.setState(history: history);
  }

  render() {    
    ...
    } else if (this.state.selectedNavigation === VIEW_FINANCIERS) {
      return null
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

2. If `this.props.history` is used by parent component also. Then you can pass a function to update `history` from parent component and pass this function to your current (child) component.

```html
class ParentFinancier extends Component {
  pushHistory => (val) {
    let {history} = this.state;
    this.setState(history: history.push('/financier/'));
  }
  
  render() {
    ...
    <ViewFinancier pushHistory={this.pushHistory} ... />
  }
  ...
}



class ViewFinancier extends Component {
  ...
  } else if (this.state.selectedNavigation === VIEW_FINANCIERS) {
    this.props.pushHistory('/financier/')
    return null   
  }
  ...
}

...
```

Comment: For point#1, how can I mutate the history using setState in render method, it would again be the same situation, right?

Comment: I used the 1st method as per my code flow... I am good with this. Thanks for the Help